# how to read a line and ignore some words (python)

Tags: python, io

I'm reading a text file line by line and i want to ignore all occurrences of "and" , "To" and "From" and return the rest. Is there a function in python that will allow me to do that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use replace or split the line on spaces and reassemble without the words that you don't need, e.g.:

```
In [6]: testsrt = 'I\'m reading a text file line by line and i want to ignore all occurrences of and , To and From and return the rest. Is there a function in python that will allow me to do that? Thanks for your help.'

In [7]: ts = testsrt.split(' ')                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [8]: excl = ["and", "To", "From"]                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [9]: ' '.join([t for t in ts if not t in excl])                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[9]: "I'm reading a text file line by line i want to ignore all occurrences of , return the rest. Is there a function in python that will allow me to do that? Thanks for your help."
```

Note that if you leave the quotes on then the words are not removed as this is working word by word.

You could also look at `re.replace` as a way of proceeding.

Comment: by any chance, do you know of a way that i can tell it to ignore all integers in my line?

Comment: re is your friend there!